# python xlrd index array out of range in matrix format

Tags: python, matrix, xlrd, index-error

I would like to build a dict using a concatenation of column and row headers as the keys. In this format cell (0,0) is blank

[image]

I want the script to start at the second column heading, concatenate its string value to the second row value in the first column, then the second row, and so forth until there are no more rows. If the corresponding cell value in column[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtOU.jpg) row[i] is blank, it should skip making a key. If it is not blank, it should make the key with the corresponding cell value as it's value.

So, 0.5_20.00 would not be created; and .05_32.00: 9.00 would be created

Once it reaches the last row, it should move to the third column (column[2]) and do the same thing until there are no more columns.

```
import xlrd

#make dict from excel workbook, size and frequency

serParams = {}
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"S:\Shared\Service_Levels.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# Get row range value

row_range_value = 0
for i in sh.col(0):
    row_range_value += 1
row_range_value = row_range_value -1
print row_range_value

# Get column range value

column_range_value = 0
for i in sh.row(0):
    column_range_value += 1
column_range_value = column_range_value - 1
print column_range_value

# build the dict by using concatenated column and row headers as keys and
# corresponding values as key value

for i in range(0,column_range_value,1):
    for j in range(0,row_range_value,1):
        if sh.cell(i+1,j+1).value != '':
            key = str(sh.cell(i+1,j).value) +"_"+str(sh.cell(i,j+1).value)
            serParams[key] = sh.cell(i+1, j+1).value
```

Maybe the format of my data is causing the index error because the ranges exceed the table data with i+1 and j+1 once the loop reaches the end of the table? I tried to address this by subtracting 1 from the range values but I continue to get the index error.

Comment: you should add `print i` and `print j` inside the last for loops to isolate what's going wrong

Comment: Looks like I might had my column, row indexing backwards. I just figured it 0,1 = A,2. Also "key = str(sh.cell(i+1,j).value) +"_"+str(sh.cell(i,j+1).value)" should be "key = str(sh.cell(0,i+1).value)+"_"+str(sh.cell(j+1,0).value)"